# Writing regular expression that selects lines containing any of the following words: linux windows solaris macos

Tags: java, regex

```
"^linux$ || ^windows$ || ^solaris$ || ^macos$"
```

I'm doing regular expressions in codelab. It's asking me to: "Write a regular expression that selects lines containing any of the following words: linux   windows solaris macos. For this exercise you must surround your solution with double quotes."

I'm getting this error message:

> "Problem: ^linux$ || ^windows$ || ^solaris$ || ^macos$ accepted:
>   unix."

How do I fix this code?

Comment: "How to fix this code?": read a tutorial about regex, think by yourself, and stop to  believe that the copy/paste can help you in your developper carrier.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(linux|windows|solaris|macos)$
```

Pipe `|` provides the alternation, parenthesis `()` limit the alternation to a set group.

Comment: bloodyKnuckles, unfortunately your code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

putting it in parentheses  and using a single pipe is the way to do it with regex

(linux|windows|solaris|macos)

@bloodyknuckles answer will only find strings starting with and ending with one of the matched words. remove the carrot and dollar sign

here is a nice tool to test http://regexpal.com/

Comment: my fingers are to fast for my brain. I corrected it.

Comment: @BrianMcCall Brian, unfortunately your code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\b` to the beginning and end for the word boundary construct:

```
"\\\b(windows|linux|solaris|macos)\\\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this and got passed:

"(linux|windows|solaris|macos)\\b"

Answer (score 0):

Excellent!

"(linux|windows|solaris|macos)\b"

Comment: Did you mean `(linux|windows|solaris|macos)\\b`? In your answer there's only one slash visible. You could put it inside a code span or code block if you want to make both of the slashes visible.